# Using Git with Eclipse causing lots of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I made a HelloWorld app in Eclipse that had no errors and runs fine. It was located in

```
Android/workspace/HelloWorld
```

Then I created a Git repo elsewhere in, say

```
Git/MyApp
```

I want to have MyApp contain the HelloWorld project from eclipse, and when I make edits to HelloWorld, it will show up in git status and I can commit and push those changes.

I tried copying the HelloWorld directory from the workspace into MyApp, then pushing my changes to my repo, which was fine.

Then I deleted the original HelloWorld in the workspace, went to Eclipse, hit import existing project, and selected the HelloWorld from the MyApp repo. But this resulted in a ton of compilation errors. How can I do what I'm trying to do without all these errors?

I've attached a link to a screenshot of the errors I get upon compilation.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Understood your problem,your project have a relationship with appcompact.Whenever you import your project you have to check below scenario,

Right click your project ---->select properties--->In side bar select "Android" Tab--->now you can see Project build target and Library Box--->in Library box click add and choose appcompact project and then  click apply.

After done above one clean and build your project.Then it will work fine.

Comment: while creating a project appcompact was referred automatically by your project,once you try reimport manually you have to refer the appcompact project because library and  android v4 jar thing hold by the app compact

Answer (score 1):

try **Clean** operation on your project and then build your project. replay whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: Okay I edited my eclipse.ini file and added -clean to the top, removed HelloWorld from the workspace, restarted Eclipse, added HelloWorld back to workspace, and still the same 12 errors.

Comment: I think you understood me wrong; i meant. In the menu items of ADT or Eclipse whatever you use, go to "Project" "menu" and in the "menu" select "Clean". Then try rebuilding or select "Build Automatically" in the same "Project" menu, then let me knwow

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact it looks to me like your eclipse doesnt recognize your app-compat anymore.
This happend to me once too, after I closed and reopend the appcompat-project.

Try to close all your projects -> open the appcompat first -> restart eclipse and maybe do a clean on your project

Hope this helps.